# Combining Steering Forces

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-physics

I am trying to understand how to implement and combine steering vectors for autonomous agents as described by Craig Reynolds.

My understanding is that each steering force should be calculated separately and then all of the steering forces should be added together and then applied.

I understand that each steering force is equal to the desired velocity for a particular behavior, minus the agent's current velocity.

I am trying to combine two basic behaviors: Seek and Flee. Below are two diagrams to illustrate my issue.

[image: Cumulative steering force at rest]

I have an agent that is Seeking a target directly ahead of it, and fleeing from a target below it. When the agent is at rest (current velocity = 0), the steering forces for each behavior are equal to their respective desired velocities:

vSteer = vDesired - currentVelocity = vDesired - 0 = vDesired

And the combined steering force points up and to the right, in blue.
This is roughly what I would expect.

However, if the agent is moving, we get a completely different result. For the sake of simplicity, say the agent is already moving at top speed in the direction of the target. So the agent's current velocity is equal to its desired seek velocity.

[image]

When the agent's current velocity is equal to the desired seek velocity, then the seek steering force is 0 (vSteer = current - desired = desired - desired = 0). The flee steering force then is equal to the desired flee velocity minus the current velocity, which produces a vector that points BACKWARD! And since the seek steering force is zero, the total steering force equals the flee steering force.

I noticed this issue while trying to implement a separation force, which is essentially the situation illustrated in the diagrams but with the red X representing a neighboring agent. The net effect is that agents maintain separation, but move at about half speed, with a seek steering force pointing forward, a flee steering force pointing backward and away from the neighbor, that largely end up cancelling each other out.

It really doesn't seem like any component of the flee force should be pointing backwards here. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to subtract the current velocity from each individual component.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but everything I have read on the subject explicitly says that you are. See here: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-movement-manager--gamedev-4278

Specifically, the implementation of doSeek, about a quarter down the page, returns desired.subtract(host.getVelocity())

Comment: Ask yourself this, "Why would the answer be different if you have two desired velocities, versus one that's the sum of those two?"

Answer (score 1):

You are not misunderstanding anything; according to the definition of the flee steering force given in the [Tuts+ article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-flee-and-arrival--gamedev-1303), this behaviour is expected. The definition introduces an undesirable steering velocity component when combined with other behaviours, which is clearly the problem you are experiencing. To work around this, the flee behaviour itself must be changed.

The sole goal of the flee behaviour is to ensure that the agent does not move *toward* the target. Thus, for an equally desirable result, the flee behaviour can be modified to satisfy the following constraint -- the component of velocity along the vector from the agent to the target (henceforth referred to as the radius vector) must be non-positive. The reasoning lies in the fact that if the velocity component along the radius vector is positive, the distance between the agent and the target decreases with every timestep.

Mathematically, our constraint becomes:

```
dot(radius, velocity) <= 0
```

Where `radius = targetPos - agentPos`.

We now have to apply a steering force (or more accurately, impulse) that ensures that the agent satisfies our flee behaviour constraint. To that end, the steering impulse becomes the negative of the velocity component along the radius vector (to cancel out the component) plus a small bias term (to "inject" momentum so that the agent moves further away from the target in the long run). Note that we only have to apply the steering force if the constraint is *not satisfied*.

Our flee behaviour constraint algorithm will look like so:

```
radius = targetPos - agentPos
radiusVel = dot(radius, velocity)

if radiusVel <= 0 {
    return
}

BIAS = 0.02      // Can be any small value determined after testing
steering = -(radiusVel + BIAS) * radius
```

In fact, this flee behaviour constraint is very similar to the normal constraint used to resolve collisions in physics engines. This normal constraint, in line with its name, applies an impulse only in the normal direction and does not affect the velocity in the tangential direction. Specifically, it will not apply a steering impulse in the "backwards" direction in your example.